# Argparse expected one argument

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='macc', usage='macc [options] [address]')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='Lists MAC Addresses')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

def list_macs():
  print("Found the following MAC Addresses")
```

I get an error when running with `python macc.py -l` it says that an argument was expected. Even when I change my code to `parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='Lists MAC Addresses' default=1)` I get the same error.

Comment: I am not an expert on argparse, but what it is saying is that there must be a value after "-l" option. If you run it using 'macc.py -l address_1' (or whatever value), it works!

Comment: The problem is clearer if you don't override the usage: `macc [-h] [-l LIST]`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The default action for an argument is `store`, which sets the value of the attribute in the namespace returned by `parser.parse_args` using the next command line argument.

You don't want to store *any* particular value; you just want to acknowledge that `-l` was used. A quick hack would be to use the `store_true` action (which would set `args.list` to `True`).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='macc')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='store_true', help='Lists MAC Addresses')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.list:
    list_macs()
```

The `store_true` action implies `type=bool` and `default=False` as well.

---

However, a slightly cleaner approach would be to define a subcommand named `list`. With this approach, your invocation would be `macc.py list` rather than `macc.py --list`.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='macc')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd_name')
subparsers.add_parser('list')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.cmd_name == "list":
    list_macs()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the argument `-l` on the cli you need to specify an argument, like:

```
python macc.py -l something
```

If you set `default = 1` on the `-l` argument you can run your script without using it like this:

```
python macc.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by setting a default value and set `nargs='?'`.

If nothing is provided after `-l`, the default value is saved for the argument. It would look something like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', help='Lists MAC Addresses', default=1, nargs='?')
```

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs