# argparse Typeerror in pandas dataframe, improper execution

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to create a small utility program to achieve the following. I provide the dataframe and choose 1 of the three options.

```
import argparse
import platform
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def version_print():
    print('Expression file is valid...')
    print("Using Python version:", platform.python_version())
    print("Using Pandas version:", pd.__version__)
    print("Using Numpy version:", np.__version__)

def normalize(df,col):
    '''Normalize the log table with desired column, 
    Enter the column value in "col".'''
    return df.sub(df[col], axis=0)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''Manipulate tables ''',
    usage='python3 %(prog)s -e *.tsv --options -op *.tsv',
    epilog='''Short prog. desc:\
    Pass the expression matrix to filter, log2(val) etc.,''')

parser.add_argument("-e","--expr", metavar='', required=True, help="tab-delimited expression matrix file")
parser.add_argument("-op","--outprefix", metavar='', required=True, help="output file prefix")
parser.add_argument("-l","--log2p5", metavar='', required=False, help="convert expression values to log2(df+0.5)")
parser.add_argument("-ft","--filter", metavar='', required=False, nargs='?', default=2, type=int, help="Filter table with tpm <= default(2)")
parser.add_argument("-nm","--normalize", metavar='', required=False, nargs=1, type=str, help="Normalize table based on column chosen")

args=parser.parse_args()

if (os.path.isfile(args.expr)):
    version_print()
    df = pd.read_csv(args.expr, sep='\t'); print(df.head(3))
    if(args.filter):
        print(args.filter, type(args.filter))
        filtered_df = df[(df[df.columns] >= 2).any(axis='columns')]
        outfile = args.outprefix + ".filteredTpm.gt." +str(args.filter)+".tsv"
        filtered_df.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False)
        print("Filtered table written to ", outfile)
    elif(args.log2p5):
        log_df = np.log2(df+0.5)
        outfile = args.outprefix + ".log2p5.tsv"
        log_df.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False)
        print("Converted table into log2p5 and output written to ", outfile)
    elif(args.normalize):
        norm_df = normalize(df, args.normalize)
        outfile = args.outprefix + ".normalized.tsv"
        norm_df.to_csv(outfile, sep='\t', index=False)
        print("Normalized table written to ", outfile)
    else:
        print("Provide valid option...")
else:
    print("Please provide proper input..")
```

Executing this shows the following:

```
python tpmTable_utilities.py -h        
usage: python3 tpmTable_utilities.py -e *.tsv --options -op *.tsv                                                                                                            

Manipulate tables

optional arguments:
  -h, --help           show this help message and exit
  -e , --expr          tab-delimited expression matrix file
  -op , --outprefix    output file prefix
  -l , --log2p5        convert expression values to log2(df+0.5)
  -ft [], --filter []  Filter table with tpm <= default(2)
  -nm , --normalize    Normalize table based on column chosen
```

When I give a dataframe, I get the error:

```
Expression file is valid...
Using Python version: 3.6.7
Using Pandas version: 1.1.2
Using Numpy version: 1.19.2
  id   c1   c2  c3   c4   c5  c6   c7
0  A  8.3   8.3   5.8   5.3   5.1   5.0   5.6
1  B  8.2   6.2   7.8  14.6   6.1   3.8   5.3
2  C  6.7  12.6  24.3   8.2  30.4  25.1  28.7

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Though I give `python TpmUtilities.py -e table.tsv -op output -l` or the other option (-nm), I still get the same error. Also for -l, I get error: expected one arguement. I guess the error is in args.filter step and I am not sure, why it gets executed in first place, since it is in if loop.

Why does this happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the traceback, that is, identify exactly where that `TypeError` is occuring.  You need to separate `argparse` errors (`expected one argument`) from the database errors that occur after parsing.  I recommend adding a `print(args)` statement so you have clear idea what the parser produced.  If that is ok, then the problem isn't in the parsing.

Comment: I see one use of `>=`:`filtered_df = df[(df[df.columns] >= 2).any(axis='columns')]`.  Test the parts of that expression, and pay particular attention to what `df[df.columns]` produces.

Comment: Got the problem. Since it is in outerloop, once the df is valid, it goes to filter, whose value is by default 2. printing the args produced ``Namespace(expr='test_averageTPM.tsv', filter=2, log2p5=None, normalize=['0H'], outprefix='test_averageTPM.filteredTpm.gt2')``

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64710034/argparse-typeerror-in-pandas-dataframe-improper-execution/64711001#comment114416769_64710034), the issue is the >= 2 comparison in line 36. The root cause of this is the "id"-column, which is not numeric and hence cannot be compared to an integer.

A straight forward way to prevent this is to convert the array in the filter [to numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html), coercing strings to NaN:

```
df[df.columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') >= 2
```

This has the downside of loosing all information in the id-column during filtering, so if you still require this, you would need to exclude this column from the filter.

Comment: The data is standard format. Hence, I change ``df = pd.read_csv(args.expr, sep='\t', index_col=0);``. Now this section works. But log section isn't working. I still get the error: tpmTable_utilities.py: error: argument -l/--log2p5: expected one argument

Comment: This is a different error and caused by argparse expecting a following argument to the "-l"-flag. A workaround for this behaviour can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363350/9501624

Comment: Yes. you are right. After I re-ran it, it still gave that error.

Comment: action='store_true' helped but, still the other sections execute. Need to find a way to stop that.

Comment: Well, the reason for that is the following: You are setting a default value for filter, namely 2. Hence, your if-tree will always enter the first option (args.filter) and neglect all other elif options.

Comment: Yeah, I removed it. But ``return`` or ``break`` is not helping either. Don't know how to run each task independently and not invoke others.