# Argparse 'argument 1 must be str, bytes or bytearray, not None'

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import sys
from scapy.all import *
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("--remote_host")
parser.add_argument("--verbose")
parser.add_argument("--help", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.help:
    print("HELP...")

# Define end host and TCP port range
hostInput    = args.remote_host
host  = socket.gethostbyname(hostInput)
port_range = [21,22,23,25,53,80,110,135,137,138,139,443,1433,1434,8080]

# Send SYN with random Src Port for each Dst port
for dst_port in port_range:
    src_port = random.randint(1025,65534)
    resp = sr1(
        IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"),timeout=1,
        verbose=int(args.verbose),
    )

    if resp is None:
        print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is filtered (silently dropped).")

    elif(resp.haslayer(TCP)):
        if(resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12):
            # Send a gratuitous RST to close the connection
            send_rst = sr(
                IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags='R'),
                timeout=1,
                verbose=int(args.verbose),
            )
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is open.")

        elif (resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14):
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is closed.")

    elif(resp.haslayer(ICMP)):
        if(
            int(resp.getlayer(ICMP).type) == 3 and
            int(resp.getlayer(ICMP).code) in [1,2,3,9,10,13]
        ):
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is filtered (silently dropped).")
```

running with `--remote_host 127.0.0.1 --verbose 1` works fine, no errors

running with `--help` produces:

```
TypeError: gethostbyname() argument 1 must be str, bytes or bytearray, not None
```

NOTE:  The above error of course only appears if I include all the lines below `print("Help...")`

Here is the full traceback:

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
= RESTART: C:\Users\00082563\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\AT2_PythonNetworkApplications.v1.1a\Scenario 1\logger.py
HELP...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\00082563\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\AT2_PythonNetworkApplications.v1.1a\Scenario 1\logger.py", line 48, in <module>
    host  = socket.gethostbyname(hostInput)
TypeError: gethostbyname() argument 1 must be str, bytes or bytearray, not None
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argparse expected one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363298/argparse-expected-one-argument)

Comment: This would be quicker if _you'd_ search the error messages, instead of posting on SO and waiting for me to do it.

Comment: I did, it didn't help my question...

Comment: You don't seem to have tried what the answers suggest, so it's unclear why you've concluded that. And if that's true, why didn't you mention it in the question?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Think what? That you haven't tried what's in the dupe?Because you didn't write in your question "I read <proposed dupe> and tried <code snippet> but what happened was <still-wrong outcome>". Also because if you had I'm fairly sure the problem would be solved, or at least you'd be seeing a _different_ one.

Comment: I tried adding action='store_true' but it didn't work for me.  I just get another error. I will update the question...

Comment: Then research _that_ error instead. Repeat until code works. That's programming.

Comment: That error seems to be caused by code _outside_ what you've shown in the question. Most likely you're not exiting if the user asked for `--help`, causing the rest of the program to run without the other inputs that were required, but without a [mre] that's just a guess. Rather than hack around help yourself, why not provide https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#description and https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#help?

Comment: As well as the example no longer recreating the problem note that the title is out of date too.

Comment: How are you calling this script?  Add a hashbang to the top `#! /usr/bin/env python3` then set execute bit `chmod +x argparse_stuff.py`  and call it  `./argparse_stuff.py --help` - prints out `HELP...` like it's supposed to, here.

Comment: This is not an `argparse` error!  Show the full traceback if you want help.  My guess is that `scapy` is using `args.remote_host` to issue as `gethostbyname` command.  But the default fo that parser argument is `None`.  If you want to display `help` without running the rest of the code, you have `exit` (or just use the default argparse help mechanism).

Comment: full trace back added...

Comment: `if args.help:` This should probably just quit the application since `--help` is supposed to do nothing but print help info.

Comment: Thanks, so what should I use to do that?

Comment: exit() I guess after print

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the above comments, I needed to exit the program after:

```
if args.help:
    print("HELP...")
```

So in the script below, the user can add in the CLI `--remote_host google.com --verbose 0` (or verbose 1 for full verbosity...)

The user can instead use in the CLI `--help` to print the custom help section, after which the program will exit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
import sys
from scapy.all import *
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("--remote_host")
parser.add_argument("--verbose")
parser.add_argument("--help", action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()


if args.help:
    print("Help section...")
    exit()
 
# Define end host and TCP port range
hostInput    = args.remote_host
host  = socket.gethostbyname(hostInput)
port_range = [21,22,23,25,53,80,110,135,137,138,139,443,1433,1434,8080]

# Send SYN with random Src Port for each Dst port
for dst_port in port_range:
    src_port = random.randint(1025,65534)
    resp = sr1(
        IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"),timeout=1,
        verbose=int(args.verbose),
    )

    if resp is None:
        print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is filtered (silently dropped).")

    elif(resp.haslayer(TCP)):
        if(resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12):
            # Send a gratuitous RST to close the connection
            send_rst = sr(
                IP(dst=host)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags='R'),
                timeout=1,
                verbose=int(args.verbose),
            )
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is open.")

        elif (resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x14):
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is closed.")

    elif(resp.haslayer(ICMP)):
        if(
            int(resp.getlayer(ICMP).type) == 3 and
            int(resp.getlayer(ICMP).code) in [1,2,3,9,10,13]
        ):
            print(f"{host}:{dst_port} is filtered (silently dropped).")
```