# Passing optional flag to set logging handler

Tags: python, argparse

I want to add an argumanet to my python script that, if present adds the `logger.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` option, printing the logging output to the cmd line.

so far i have:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s (%(module)s.%(funcName)s): [%(levelname)s] %(message)s ",
    datefmt='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S',
    handlers=[
        logging.FileHandler("log.txt"),
    ]
)

def print_to_cmd():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)  

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='python3 main.py')
parser.add_argument('-print', 
                    help='If present,the script will output logging to CMD as well as log file',
                    type=print_to_cmd)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

but i'm getting:

```
python3 main.py: error: argument -print: expected one argument
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Argparse expected one argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363298/argparse-expected-one-argument)

Comment: Don't use `type` like this.  How are you calling this script?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the responses in the comments, this is how I solved it.

```
def print_to_cmd():
    """
    Method to set the std handler should the '-print' flag be present as an arg.
    """
    std_out_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(std_out_handler)


parser.add_argument('-print', help='If present, the script will output logging to CMD as well as log file',
                        action='store_true')
 args = parser.parse_args()
 if args.print:
     print_to_cmd()
```